# Validate schema of a list in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I receive requests from client apps via API endpoints as JSON objects, then parse them and convert to lists, like this

```
[
  {<<"firstname">>, <<"John">>},
  {<<"lastname">>, <<"Doe">>},
]
```

I have schema stating that the object must have two fields "firstname" and "lastname" as string.

Are there libraries to validate structures against schema or it can be solved with my own code relatively easily?

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/for-GET/jesse a json schema validator for erlang.